# How to express a condition in kendo grid hidden option

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are using MS Identity Framework for role-based authorization. In our application, roles are actually "permissions" to access or modify a specific tab in the application. The application consists of one main view within which there are several partial views each of which represents a tab. Those tabs contain editable Kendo grids.

Users can have a "View Only" permission to access a tab or a "View and Edit" permission. Users with a View and Edit permission for a tab can view a grid and edit any row in it through the Action column.  Users with View Only permission for a given tab should see the grids in that tab without the Action/command column.

We are already restricting the functionality related to the command column in a grid through role-based authentication in the controller. But we would also like to remove the column from view for users who have View Only access for that specific grid. I was thinking of using the Hidden() option to accomplish that.

According to Telerik, Kendo grids have the option of hiding a column conditionally using hidden("condition"). However, I cannot find examples of using that condition other than using an explicit boolean value.

Can someone give an example of the syntax used to write a more explicit condition (for example if ViewBag["clientRole"] is 1) when binding the command column in the grid (for example:

c.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy();}).**Hidden("condition")**

Unfortunately, there is no documentation or examples of the condition syntax anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option accepts only boolean. Could you please elaborate more on the exact configuration that you have?

**Edit:** 
You can achieve this by simply casting the ViewData (or the value passed to this option) to bool type:

Controller:

```
ViewData["hideColumns"] = true;
```

Grid:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDescription).Hidden((bool)ViewData["hideColumns"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have edited the question to add more context. (btw, We are using Razor)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Valdimir! I was looking for some definition of acceptable syntax if a more complex condition is to be created within the Hidden condition. We used a similar approach to yours where we create a boolean outside of the grid then use that directly in the grid.  That works for now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that this help you. You can use this approach across the Grid for various options - just check what types the option accepts.